# Can an e-mail notification be sent when a member updates their profile?

Tags: members, email, notification, member-management

Is there a way to have an e-mail notification sent to one or more addresses when a Member updates their information?

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is.

You will need to use the [member_update_start()](https://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/development/extension_hooks/global/member_model/index.html) hook.

Use it to fire a basic PHP mail()

Answer (score 1):

You could easily do this with [postmaster](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/postmaster)